# Objects defined in a static goes missing

Tags: objective-c

I'm fairly new to Objective-C development and I've encountered a weird issue lately. Basically, I have defined a static class to hold all my object references and in some of the object attributes, they also maintain references to other objects (has-a relationship).

Having accessed these object  and assigning values to them across several view controllers, I've come to realized that as time passes, the values of these object suddenly becomes empty. But some of the other objects defined in the static class doesn't.

I was wondering if anyone out there could guide me out abit as my prior experiences with other OO languages such as Java have never had this problem.

Below is a reference to the some of my codes..

```
//
//  Store.h
//  GlukoTrackr
//
//  Created by Desmond Quek on 11/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NTU. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Account.h"
#import "OrthoInjury.h"
#import "TherapyPhases.h"
#import "Exercises.h"
#import "Assessment.h"

@interface Store : NSObject
{
    //Account *account;
    Account *LoginAccount;
    OrthoInjury *orthoInjury;
    Exercises *selectedExercise;

    /* RSI */
    NSString *selectedTypeOfSplint;
    NSString *activitiesToAvoid;
    NSString *altWaysOfDoingActivities;
    NSString *comments;
    /* End of RSI */

    //Assessment
    Assessment *assesment;
    TherapyPhases *tempTherapyPhase;

    NSMutableArray *ALlExercises;

    BOOL error;
}

//@property (nonatomic,strong) Account *account;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Account *LoginAccount;

@property (nonatomic,retain) OrthoInjury *orthoInjury;
@property (nonatomic,retain) TherapyPhases *therapyPhases;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Exercises *selectedExercise;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *ALlExercises;

//Assessment
@property (nonatomic,strong) Assessment *assesment;
@property (nonatomic,retain) TherapyPhases *tempTherapyPhase;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedTypeOfSplint;


/* RSI */
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedTypeOfSplint;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *activitiesToAvoid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *altWaysOfDoingActivities;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *comments;
/* End of RSI */

//@property (nonatomic,strong) Store *md5;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL error;

+(Store *) SharedStore;

@end


//
//  Store.m
//  GlukoTrackr
//
//  Created by Desmond Quek on 11/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NTU. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Store.h"
#import "Account.h"
#import "OrthoInjury.h"
#import "TherapyPhases.h"
#import "Exercises.h"
#import "Assessment.h"
#import "RSI.h"

@implementation Store
//@synthesize account;
@synthesize LoginAccount;

@synthesize orthoInjury;
@synthesize therapyPhases;
@synthesize selectedExercise;
@synthesize  ALlExercises;
@synthesize selectedTypeOfSplint;

@synthesize comments;
@synthesize altWaysOfDoingActivities;
@synthesize  activitiesToAvoid;
@synthesize  error;


@synthesize assesment;
@synthesize tempTherapyPhase;
//@synthesize md5;

static Store *SharedStore = nil;

static OrthoInjury *orthoInjury = nil;
static TherapyPhases *therapyPhases = nil;
static Assessment *assessment = nil;
static TherapyPhases *tempTherapyPhase = nil;
+ (Store *) SharedStore
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(SharedStore == nil)
        {
            SharedStore = [[self alloc] init];
            orthoInjury = [[OrthoInjury alloc] init];
            therapyPhases = [[TherapyPhases alloc] init];

            assessment = [[Assessment alloc]init];
            tempTherapyPhase = [[TherapyPhases alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return SharedStore;
}



@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest getting rid of all the `static` variable declarations that duplicate the names of your instance variables.  Create a real `init` method to set the instance variables and call it when you're building the `SharedStore`.

Comment: Hi, could you give me an example of what you mean? Because currently to access the objects in the static class, what i'm doing in the viewcontroller.m are this...

    Store *MyStore = [Store SharedStore];
    
    Assessment* ass= MyStore.assesment;

Comment: Your code from the view controller looks fine but it's accessing the instance properties, not the static variables.  If you wanted to use the statics, you'd have to implement your own getters and there's really no point to that.  The @lupatus implementation in an alternate answer to this question is a better path to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how do you want to use all those statics and why they have same names as instance variables.

I suppose that you intended to write singleton (not static class - there is no such thing in obj-c). 
You need only one static variable then, to hold shared instance, the rest should belong to instance and you can initialize it within init.

Currently you don't have to declare property variable and then synthesize it, it's enough to declare property (at least in this case).

Additionally there is not need to import everything again in .m when it is already imported in header file.

```
//
//  Store.h
//  GlukoTrackr
//
//  Created by Desmond Quek on 11/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NTU. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Account.h"
#import "OrthoInjury.h"
#import "TherapyPhases.h"
#import "Exercises.h"
#import "Assessment.h"

@interface Store : NSObject

//@property (nonatomic,strong) Account *account;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Account *LoginAccount;

@property (nonatomic,retain) OrthoInjury *orthoInjury;
@property (nonatomic,retain) TherapyPhases *therapyPhases;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Exercises *selectedExercise;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *ALlExercises;

//Assessment
@property (nonatomic,strong) Assessment *assesment;
@property (nonatomic,retain) TherapyPhases *tempTherapyPhase;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedTypeOfSplint;


/* RSI */
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedTypeOfSplint;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *activitiesToAvoid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *altWaysOfDoingActivities;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *comments;
/* End of RSI */

//@property (nonatomic,strong) Store *md5;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL error;

+(Store *) SharedStore;

@end


//
//  Store.m
//  GlukoTrackr
//
//  Created by Desmond Quek on 11/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NTU. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Store.h"
#import "RSI.h"

@implementation Store

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.orthoInjury = [[OrthoInjury alloc] init];
        self.therapyPhases = [[TherapyPhases alloc] init];
        self.assessment = [[Assessment alloc]init];
        self.tempTherapyPhase = [[TherapyPhases alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (Store *) SharedStore {
    static Store *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```